# Unknown binary format of a b64-encoded list of doubles

Tags: decompress, encodings, unknown-data

While reverse engineering a database middleware. This is presumably encoding a list of double or float values with Base64 encoding and then compressing it.

Via `zlib.decompress()` I was able to decompress it, but I got a string of presumably multiple base64-strings. I can see that it consists of more than one, because it contains multiple `=`. But afaik, these do not always mark the end of a b64-encoded string, because one can also end without a `=`.

This is a excerpt of one field:

```
b'<\x12u<\xf4\x808=\x95\xf0U=\x9fse;\xef\xbe\xf2=A\xd1K=\x1fB\x99=\x95\x11\xa3=\xb8\xcd\xbd<\xd2\xfaL=\x1d\x80U=\xd6:\x1e=\xdcp\xcd=1\xd2\xe1=\t\x01\x8e<\x85\xa8\x16>8\xb4\xa7>2\xf4\x11=>\x03\x9b<\xdfA\x9b>%>a>\xcf\x9a\x05>Ie\x1c>\t@Y<\xdfC\xe2=\xf8\'\xb0=zpa=\x8e\xe8\xde<\xc8\xcby=\x88\xfe\xb6=\xb8Uv=\xd5\xe3\xee=q\xef|<B\xe1\x1f=%\xfe\x85=\x90_\x04=p\x9e\xbd=\x89og=\x96\x88\x87<\xa2\x9c\x84=\x969\xaf=\xab\x84^<\xef\x81\xf6<T\x7f\xf4<\x85\xd6\x86<\x80Q\x93<\xb4\xf9\x00<\xfc&s<\xb9q\x1b<\xd3\xd8\xa0<4\xe9\xc3=\x86a\xb4=\xd5s_=\xc8\xb1==\xc24\xca=~\xd3\xe8=^7\xa5=e\xa3-=\x07?4<\xd5HJ=='
```

As an amateur on this field, I am very unsure where to start.
From the documentation I know, that it's a b64-encoded list, but I don't know how to use it. Obviously, when decoded, it will consist of a binary format that in some computer language represents a list of floats.

Any tips on how to continue working on this problem?
Unfortunately I have no access to the software currently, the only thing I have is this data structure.

Sorry for my amateur questions, and thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: A Base64 string will not have \x12.....\xf4 etc  hope i am not understanding wrong here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data you have here is not base64 encoded, as that would only have letters, numbers, `+`, `/`, and (as you mentioned) `=`. The `\x` escape code in the string indicates bytes that are non-printable or outside the ASCII range.

The regular pattern of `=` or near-`=` values (`;`, `<`, `=`, `>`) every four bytes suggests that this is a simple array of 4-byte little-endian fields with values relatively close to each other. Here is what it looks like as a 4-byte (single precision) float array.

```
>>> data = b'<\x12u<\xf4\x808=\x95\xf0U=\x9fse;\xef\xbe\xf2=A\xd1K=...'
>>> struct.unpack_from('<{}f'.format(str(len(data)//4)), data)
(0.014957960695028305, 0.045044854283332825, 0.05223139002919197, 0.003501154249534011, 0.11852823942899704, 0.049760106950998306, 0.07483314722776413, 0.07962337881326675, 0.0231693834066391, 0.05004388839006424, [...])
```

Does this look like the range of values you are expecting?

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, yes! Thanks!
Quick noob question: How do you acquire this knowledge about the patterns? Any specific books, or is it just experience?